# Should I delete comments about corrections proposed, then made, to an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401681/nsbezierpath-wide-stroke-to-nsbezierpath/11403171#comment15052945_11403171), the author of the answer and I exchanged a few comments on the code.

The code is now working and the comments are irrelevant now, because there were two errors in the code, that have been corrected.

Should I remove my comment and propose the other author to do the same so that the question looks more compact ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such comments can be removed.  The problem, of course, is coordinating the effort between you and the other commenter since, if you remove only your comments (and the other commenter doesn't return to remove theirs), the remaining comments won't make any sense.

There aren't that many comments, and they are all on-topic (being clarifications of the original post).  I would just leave them.

Comment: +1 I usually let the person know I'm going to delete my side of the conversation, and do so once they acknowledge.